# Postgres: How to change the case of JSON keys?

Tags: json, postgresql

My address column is being stored as a JSON using this format:

`{
  "Street1": "800 Smithe St",
  "Street2": null,
  "City": "Vancouver",
  "Region": null,
  "State": "BC",
  "Zip": "V6Z 2E1"
}`

How can I change the column values to camel case / lowercase, so they appear like this?

`{
  "street1": "800 Smithe St",
  "street2": null,
  "city": "Vancouver",
  "region": null,
  "state": "BC",
  "zip": "V6Z 2E1"
}`

Comment: Do you care about potential duplicate keys?

Comment: Not particularly; that would make an interesting use case but this question focuses on just manipulating the keys not doing validation

Answer (score 4):

```
with j(j) as ( values ($$
  {
    "Street1": "800 Smithe St",
    "Street2": null,
    "City": "Vancouver",
    "Region": null,
    "State": "BC",
    "Zip": "V6Z 2E1"
  }
$$::jsonb))
select json_object_agg(lower(key), value)
from j, jsonb_each(j) je
group by j;
                                                       json_object_agg                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 { "zip" : "V6Z 2E1", "city" : "Vancouver", "state" : "BC", "region" : null, "street1" : "800 Smithe St", "street2" : null }
```

Comment: This. Though I'd create a function for clarity: `create or replace function jsonb_lower_keys(jsonb) returns jsonb language sql immutable strict as $$ select jsonb_object_agg(lower(key),value) from jsonb_each($1); $$;`